# Can my kitten die from playing too hard?

Tags: cats

My kittens occasionally don't play with there toy together very well the girl will hiss at the boy if she feels its her turn. oddly she waits patiently when its his turn but gets very annoyed when its her turn and he jumps in. so my idea was simply to play until both of them had enough of playing.

Sadly it didn't work the cat that instigates the problem was playing so hard that after 1.5 hours he couldn't keep his eyes open it looked like he was blinking every couple seconds cause he was so tired.

i stopped at this point cause i know some animals can actually exert themselves to death dogs,horses and bears for example. is this the same for cats? i would of liked to kept going cause the other wasn't down for the count yet.

Comment: I think theoretically perhaps, but the disposition of cats is normally to particularly avoid discomfort, so I think it's pretty darn unlikely even if it is theoretically possible. But if the cat is really obviously exhausted, best to give it a break anyways.